Launching an Application with Normal User Privileges from an Administrator-Privileged Instance
I'm developing a custom installer for my application, because I need to configure some peculiar settings that InnoSetup and other similar tools don't allow. The installer requires administrator privileges to perform the necessary configurations. At the end of the installation, it starts the newly installed application.
The problem is that this application is also launched with administrator privileges, inheriting the installer's permissions. This happens regardless of the method used to launch the application: CreateProcess, CreateProcessAsUser, ShellExecute, and even the obsolete WinExec.
In summary, my question is: From an application running with administrator privileges, how can I start another application with the "normal" privileges of the logged Windows user?

Why not develop your installer so that in the begging it starts with normal user permission and then from this installer you spawn another one that is created with elevated privileges so it can do the needed stuff. Then all you have to do is wait for the elevated instance to finish its work and in the end you launch the application from your non elevated instance. Many installers work in this way.

Interesting. However, the user can still launch the installer with the "Run as Administrator" option, where the error would occur again. Furthermore, it requires the installer to have more than one executable, which is also not good.

No need to have more than one file. You can start second instance of the same executable using RunAs and also pass special startup parameter that will tell this second instance to proceed directly to performing a specific task instead of starting in normal way. You then just monitor from your first instance to see when the second instance has been closed to continue with your installer progress.

Raymond Chen has blog articles on this very subject:
How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process and vice versa?
TLDR; ask the user's Explorer instance to run the app, by using IShell­Dispatch2.Shell­Execute().
How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process, redux
TLDR; ask CreateProcess() to make the user's Explorer instance be the parent of the app, by using the PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS attribute.

Most simply way - open the shell window, get its process id, and use this process as the parent process:
inline ULONG BOOL_TO_ERROR(BOOL f)
{
    return f ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
}

ULONG RunFromShell(PCWSTR lpApplicationName, PWSTR lpCommandLine)
{
    HWND hwnd = GetShellWindow();
    if (!hwnd)
    {
        return ERROR_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    ULONG dwProcessId;
    if (!GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwProcessId))
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    STARTUPINFOEXW si = {{ sizeof(si)}};

    SIZE_T s = 0;
    ULONG dwError;
    while (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == (dwError = BOOL_TO_ERROR(
        InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(si.lpAttributeList, 1, 0, &s))))
    {
        si.lpAttributeList = (LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST)alloca(s);
    }

    if (NOERROR == dwError)
    {
        if (HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS, FALSE, dwProcessId))
        {
            if (NOERROR == (dwError = BOOL_TO_ERROR(UpdateProcThreadAttribute(
                si.lpAttributeList, 0, PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS, &hProcess, sizeof(hProcess), 0, 0))))
            {
                PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

                if (NOERROR == (dwError = BOOL_TO_ERROR(CreateProcessW(lpApplicationName, lpCommandLine, 
                    0, 0, 0, EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT, 0, 0, &si.StartupInfo, &pi))))
                {
                    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
                    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
                }
            }

            CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }
    }

    return dwError;
}

Another possible way, probably more correct, but requires more code, is to get the user token via WTSQueryUserToken(), and then use this token in a call to CreateProcessAsUser(). For this, you need to have SeTcbPrivilege, SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege and SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege. The admin can get these privileges, but enum process, open it tokens, one by one, check that required privilege exist in token, if found - impersonate with this token and after this call WTSQueryUserToken() + CreateProcessAsUser().
#define echo(x) x
#define label(x) echo(x)##__LINE__

#define BEGIN_PRIVILEGES(name, n) static const union { TOKEN_PRIVILEGES name;\
struct { ULONG PrivilegeCount; LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Privileges[n];} label(_) = { n, {

#define LAA(se) {{se}, SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED }

#define END_PRIVILEGES }};};

BEGIN_PRIVILEGES(tp_AssignTcb, 3)
    LAA(SE_TCB_PRIVILEGE),
    LAA(SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_PRIVILEGE),
    LAA(SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_PRIVILEGE),
END_PRIVILEGES

NTSTATUS ImpersonateToken(_In_ const TOKEN_PRIVILEGES* RequiredSet);
NTSTATUS RtlRevertToSelf();

HRESULT RunAsUser(PCWSTR lpApplicationName, PWSTR lpCommandLine)
{
    NTSTATUS status = ImpersonateToken(&tp_AssignTcb);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        HANDLE hToken;
        //ProcessIdToSessionId(GetCurrentProcessId(), &SessionId);
        if (NOERROR == (status = BOOL_TO_ERROR(WTSQueryUserToken(RtlGetCurrentPeb()->SessionId, &hToken))))
        {
            STARTUPINFOW si = { sizeof(si) };
            PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
            
            if (NOERROR == (status = BOOL_TO_ERROR(CreateProcessAsUserW(hToken, 
                lpApplicationName, lpCommandLine, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi))))
            {
                CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
                CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
            }
            CloseHandle(hToken);
        }
        RtlRevertToSelf();
    }

    return status;
}

NTSTATUS RtlRevertToSelf()
{
    HANDLE hToken = 0;
    return NtSetInformationThread(NtCurrentThread(), ThreadImpersonationToken, &hToken, sizeof(hToken));
}

extern const SECURITY_QUALITY_OF_SERVICE sqos = {
    sizeof (sqos), SecurityImpersonation, SECURITY_DYNAMIC_TRACKING, FALSE
};

extern const OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa_sqos = { sizeof(oa_sqos), 0, 0, 0, 0, const_cast<SECURITY_QUALITY_OF_SERVICE*>(&sqos) };

NTSTATUS ImpersonateToken(_In_ PVOID buf, _In_ const TOKEN_PRIVILEGES* RequiredSet)
{
    NTSTATUS status;

    union {
        PVOID pv;
        PBYTE pb;
        PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi;
    };

    pv = buf;
    ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;

    do 
    {
        pb += NextEntryOffset;

        HANDLE hProcess, hToken, hNewToken;

        CLIENT_ID ClientId = { pspi->UniqueProcessId };

        if (ClientId.UniqueProcess)
        {
            if (0 <= NtOpenProcess(&hProcess, PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, 
                const_cast<POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES>(&oa_sqos), &ClientId))
            {
                status = NtOpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_DUPLICATE, &hToken);

                NtClose(hProcess);

                if (0 <= status)
                {
                    status = NtDuplicateToken(hToken, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES|TOKEN_IMPERSONATE|TOKEN_QUERY, 
                        const_cast<POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES>(&oa_sqos), FALSE, TokenImpersonation, &hNewToken);

                    NtClose(hToken);

                    if (0 <= status)
                    {
                        status = NtAdjustPrivilegesToken(hNewToken, FALSE, const_cast<PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES>(RequiredSet), 0, 0, 0);

                        if (STATUS_SUCCESS == status)   
                        {
                            status = NtSetInformationThread(NtCurrentThread(), ThreadImpersonationToken, &hNewToken, sizeof(hNewToken));
                        }

                        NtClose(hNewToken);

                        if (STATUS_SUCCESS == status)
                        {
                            return STATUS_SUCCESS;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } while (NextEntryOffset = pspi->NextEntryOffset);

    return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
}

NTSTATUS ImpersonateToken(_In_ const TOKEN_PRIVILEGES* RequiredSet)
{
    NTSTATUS status;

    ULONG cb = 0x40000;

    do 
    {
        status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;

        if (PBYTE buf = new BYTE[cb += 0x1000])
        {
            if (0 <= (status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, buf, cb, &cb)))
            {
                status = ImpersonateToken(buf, RequiredSet);

                if (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
                {
                    status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
                }
            }

            delete [] buf;
        }

    } while(status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

    return status;
}


Your 1st suggestion is not the simplest way. SilverWarrior suggested an even simpler approach. As for your 2nd suggestion, an admin user can't call WTSQueryUserToken(), only the SYSTEM account can call it. It's documentation even says so.

@RemyLebeau admin can of course, and i describe how - impersonate with token, which have TCB ( and other privileges for CreateProcessAsUser ). I by self do this huge counts

"To call this function successfully, the calling application must be running within the context of the LocalSystem account and have the SE_TCB_NAME privilege."

@RemyLebeau documentation is wrong. Need only TCB. Or you want say that my code is wrong and not work ?

Thanks for all the answers. Here is the final code based on them, in Delphi.
// reimport - Windows.pas has wrong args (Delphi 11)
function InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(lpAttributeList: PProcThreadAttributeList; dwAttributeCount, dwFlags: DWORD;
  var lpSize: Cardinal): ByteBool; stdcall; external kernel32;

function UpdateProcThreadAttribute(lpAttributeList: PProcThreadAttributeList; dwFlags: DWORD; Attribute: Cardinal;
  lpValue: Pointer; cbSize: Cardinal; lpPreviousValue: Pointer; lpReturnSize: PCardinal): ByteBool; stdcall;
  external kernel32;

procedure DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(lpAttributeList: PProcThreadAttributeList); stdcall; external kernel32;

// not declared in Windows.pas
type
  TStartupInfoEx = record
    StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
    lpAttributeList: PProcThreadAttributeList;
  end;

const
  EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT = $00080000;
  PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS = $00020000;

// get explorer.exe id
function GetProcessIDFromExplorer: DWORD;
var
  Handle: THandle;
  ProcEntry: TProcessEntry32;
begin
  Result := 0;

  Handle := CreateToolHelp32SnapShot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, 0);
  ProcEntry.dwSize := SizeOf(TProcessEntry32);
  Process32First(Handle, ProcEntry);

  repeat
    if SameText(ProcEntry.szExeFile, 'explorer.exe') then
      Exit(ProcEntry.th32ProcessID);
  until not Process32Next(Handle, ProcEntry);

  CloseHandle(Handle);
end;

procedure StartApplication(const AExeName: string);
var
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcessInformation: TProcessInformation;
  Handle: THandle;
  hProcess, Pid, Size: Cardinal;
  StartupInfoEx: TStartupInfoEx;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@StartupInfoEx, SizeOf(StartupInfoEx));
  // explorer.exe handle
  // according to @RbMm you can use the line below
  // GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetShellWindow, Pid);
  // but for some strange reason it's not working for me. So I used
  Pid := GetProcessIDFromExplorer;

  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS, False, Pid);

  InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(nil, 1, 0, Size);
  GetMem(StartupInfoEx.lpAttributeList, Size);
  InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(StartupInfoEx.lpAttributeList, 1, 0, Size);
  UpdateProcThreadAttribute(StartupInfoEx.lpAttributeList, 0, PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS, @hProcess,
    SizeOf(THandle), nil, nil);

  with StartupInfoEx.StartupInfo do
  begin
    cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfoEx);
    wShowWindow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
  end;

  try
    if not CreateProcess(PChar(AExeName), nil, nil, nil, False,
      CREATE_NO_WINDOW or EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT, nil, nil, StartupInfoEx.StartupInfo, ProcessInformation) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  finally
    DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(StartupInfoEx.lpAttributeList);
    FreeMem(StartupInfoEx.lpAttributeList);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
  end;
end;


Enumerate processes and search explorer by name - this is exactly what not need todo, for get it id. Also can be several explorers processes in case several rdp sessions

I hadn't thought about that. I can also get the ParentId of the current installer. Do you think it's safer?

GetShellWindow + GetWindowThreadProcessId

I tried it, returned 0.

https://ibb.co/mS17zF6

What is return 0 ? This can be only in case no shell process ( ie explorer usually) running. Look at my answers. I paste here even 2 ways ( second probably usually not need, again only in case no shell process) and my code is absolute correct

And despite i don't know Delphi, how you call GetWindowThreadProcessId look like wrong. Last parameter must be @Pid probably. And main - you need use debuger for debug code, not messageboxes

I used messagebox to get a visible value for a printscreen.

use debugger is always better. and your code is wrong if you get pid is 0

GetWindowThreadProcessId  is called correctly; in Delphi this procedure has a variable parameter, something like "pass by reference".

I will get parentId from current process, it will work too. Thanks for your help.

if i say, i better know. if GetWindowThreadProcessId return not 0 thread id, the pid also can not be 0.
